# Unit Testing Flink Functions

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, apache-flink

I am using Flink v.1.4.0.

I have implemented a module, as part of a package I am developing, whose role is to deduplicate a stream. The module is quite simple:

```
public class RemoveDuplicateFilter<T> extends RichFlatMapFunction<T, T> {

static final ValueStateDescriptor<Boolean> SEEN_DESCRIPTOR = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("seen", Boolean.class);
private ValueState<Boolean> seen;

@Override
public void open(Configuration configuration) {
  RuntimeContext runtimeContext = this.getRuntimeContext();
  seen = runtimeContext.getState(SEEN_DESCRIPTOR);  
}

@Override
public void flatMap(T value, Collector<T> out) throws Exception {
  Boolean hasBeenSeen = seen.value();

  if(hasBeenSeen == null || !hasBeenSeen) {
    out.collect(value);
    seen.update(true);
  }  
}
```

The question is: how do I test this code without having to instantiate an actual `Flink` ValueState? i.e. using Mockito?

I have tried a number of things but, essentially, when it comes down to calling:

```
RuntimeContext runtimeContext = Mockito.mock(RuntimeContext.class);
...
when(runtimeContext.getState(SEEN_DESCRIPTOR)).thenReturn(seen);
```

The call always fails. I have tried replacing the `SEEN_DESCRIPTOR` with `Matchers.any()` but still no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flinkspector](https://github.com/ottogroup/flink-spector) to do unit-testing of functions.